# laravel perform two query in one function

Tags: php, laravel

Simply i have a two table

> GALLARIES AND MEDIA

In a GALLARIES  table id,title,venueId i have saved gallary folder name for the particular venue.
In MEDIA Table I have id,imagepath,is_thumb(0 or 1),gallery_Id

What i want to do is when i set is_thumb_image(1) then i have call two function

> 1 st for unset image all with gallery_id and after i call second function for set is_thumb_image for particular image.

Is it possible to call one function only and perform both functionalty.

Here is my Controller code.

```
        $albumId = $request->album_id; //table galleries id  - album name
        if($request->is_thumb_image == "true") { 
            $media1->UnsetThumbImage($albumId); // first unset thumb_image 
            $media->setThumbImage($media->id); // call for set thumb_image 
        } else {
            $request->is_banner_image = false;
        }
```

Here is my model functions

```
 public function setThumbImage($mediaId) {
   try {
        DB::table('media')
            ->where('id', $mediaId)
            ->update(['is_thumb_image' => 1]);
        $this->is_thumb_image = 1;
    } catch (\Exception $ex) {
        echo $ex->getMessage();
        dd($ex->getTraceAsString());
    }
}

public function UnsetThumbImage($albumid) {
    DB::table('media')
    ->where('gallery_id', $albumid)
    ->update(['is_thumb_image' => 0]);
    $this->is_thumb_image = 1;
}
```

How can i do it calling only one function.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [CASE with MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html) to update on various conditions. You'd need to use a [raw query](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#raw-expressions) to do this with Laravel I believe.

Something like:

```
UPDATE media
SET is_thumb_image = CASE
    WHEN id = $mediaId THEN 1
    WHEN gallery_id = $albumId THEN 0
END
```

Comment: Help me to set in laravel quey.

Answer (score 0):

For that you need to:
specify which column is it gonna be. But best practice is to do this in different methods, as they have different jobs, and column action.

```
$this->setThumbImage('id', $id);
$this->setThumbImage('gallery_id', $id);
```

Pass what you need to according to your requirement.

```
public function setThumbImage($id, $field) {
    DB::table('media')
      ->where("$field", $id)
      ->update(['is_thumb_image' => 0]);
$this->is_thumb_image = 1;
```

}

Comment: I believe the person asking wanted to consolidate the 2 queries into 1.

Comment: That's pretty much same thing, he can use raw query for that you know, I just did this because he said he needs that in one function.

Comment: to do this in different methods is good or shd i go with one query ?

Comment: did you try the method i answered? try once.